# Which conjunction should I use?

Tags: phrase-meaning, conjunctions

"From figure 1, we can see that A is higher than B, and **from** the data in table 1, it could be illustrated that A is 5 times higher than B."

My gut feeling is that the "from" is naive, which I want to say that combining figure 1 and table 2, we can suggest that A is 5 times higher than B. So how to alter "from" by another conjunction phrase which could make the sentence more idiomatic?

Comment: "From" is perfectly idiomatic. That said, if you're dead set on replacing it (maybe because it feels redundant with the sentence's initial *from*), you could also use *by*.

Comment: But I want to use a phrase containing "combining table 1", is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

"*Simplify:*

"From figure 1, we can see that A is higher than B, and the data in table 1 illustrates that A is 5 times higher than B.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> From figure 1, we can see that A is higher than B, and **using** the data in table 1, it could be illustrated that A is 5 times higher than B."